# How to handle Nested events in RX Java

Tags: java, spring, rx-java, reactive-programming

I am quite new to RX java and I am facing an issue. Where I have sets of events, and output of one event has to be feed as an input of another event, and there could be n number of events . I was trying to do that in a following way .

```
    public Single<List<EventMetaData>> executeAction(Long blogId){

    Single<BlogPostData> dbblogPostData = manager.findById(blogId);


    Single<BlogPostData> chain = dbblogPostData;
    List<Single<BlogPostData>> allBlogPost = new ArrayList<>();
    allSnapshots.add(dbblogPostData);


    for (EventEntry eventEntry : Events) {
        // create a chain where response of one event is passed to next event


        chain = chain.flatMap(blogPostData -> {
            Single<BlogPostData> newSnapshot = executeEvent(eventEntry, blogPostData);

            return newSnapshot;
        });


        allBlogPost.add(chain);

    }

    return  Single.zip(allBlogPost, objects -> {
                List<blogPostData> snapshotEntries = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Object obj : objects) {
                    snapshotEntries.add((blogPostData) obj);
                }
                return getMetaData(snapshotEntries);
            });
}


 private Single<BlogPostData> executeEvent(Event event, BlogPostData blogpostEntry) throws ManagerException {



    Single<BlogPostData> clientSnapshotSingle =
            facade.getSnpashotFromClient(blogpostEntry, event);


    return clientSnapshotSingle.flatMap(
            blogPost -> {

               // Do some logic here on get new Snapshot,  that needs to be save it to DB


                blogpostEntry = utils.getDBUpdatableData(blogpostEntry, event.getRefId);
                if (event.isDbupdatable) {

                     // This methods returns Single<BlogPostData>
                    return manager.create(blogpostEntry);
                }
                return Single.just(blogpostEntry);
            });

}
```

Now If I have two events, let's say e1, e2. This code

```
chain.flatMap(blogPostData -> { Single<BlogPostData> newSnapshot = executeEvent(eventEntry, blogPostData);
      return newSnapshot;}
```

is getting executed 3 times( twice for event e1 and once for e2).When I subscribe it like this.And for 4 events it will totally 6 times.

```
 Single<List<EventMetaData>> listOfMeta;
     (listOfMeta.subscribe());
```

To Simplify my example . When executeAction gets called , I pick up the blog entry from DB , and then run a sets of event over (via executeEvent() call) it . Now since all the events are sequential , I need to pass the output of first event to input of second events and so on . I as well store all the outputs of the events in List `List<Single> allBlogPost` to run some calculation over it `Single.zip(allBlogPost)` .

So can someone help me figure out what is wrong with my code , and how can I execute all the event exactly (If I should use any other operator to do so ) n times and also pass result of one event to other.

Comment: You don't clear `chain` after adding it to the `allBlogPost` list. As you keep adding events, the number of times `executeEvent()` is called will keep growing. You will call it for `e1`, then `e1` and `e2`, then `e1` and `e2` and `e3`, etc.

Comment: @BobDalgleish  Exactly is my problem . But I am yet to find the solution here ,not sure if any other operator can do the job for me.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Any way to simplify your example and add some narrative?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I have updated it .So basically I am trying to execute series of event on blogPost and pass the response of one to another in sequence and add these response to allBlogPost List . And finally run some calculation over allBlogPost list .Hope this helps you .